# Scrolling UITextView inside UIPageViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I have `UIPageViewController` with transition style scroll and navigation orientation vertical. In one of the `UIViewControllers` I have a `UITextView`. When I try to scroll inside the text view sometimes `UIPageViewController` catches the pan gesture and tries to move to next view controller. What would be solution to stop `UIPageViewController` to receive touch events when a user scrolls text view?

I tried to set `exclusiveTouch=YES` for the text view, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. You can disable UIPageViewController panning when UITextView is scrolling.

To disable or enable UIPageViewController panning:

```
-(void)enablePanning:(BOOL) enable
{
    for (UIScrollView *view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            view.scrollEnabled = enable;
        }
    }
}
```

And to know when UITextView is scrolling we can use UITextViewDelegate methods:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    [self enablePanning:YES];
}

-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
     [self enablePanning:NO];
}
```